# How can I watch a MongoDB document for changes without a client?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How could I watch a MongoDB document for changes and then trigger a function without having a client connected to my meteor site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How could meteor know MongoDB changes instantly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744661/how-could-meteor-know-mongodb-changes-instantly)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the linked question is more about architecture while this asks for a single recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In server code:

```
var docId = "someDocumentId";

var handle = FooCollection.find(docId).observeChanges({
  changed: function(id, fields) {
    // Trigger your callback
  }
});

// ... Some time later, to clean up

handle.stop();
```

For more information on what you can pass to `observeChanges`, and the arguments you get back, see [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes). This is a specific case of the general `observeChanges` usage, which allows you to watch multiple documents at once and get callbacks for many different types of events.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have this working for one document.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have created a monster. Even after commenting out my code it is still observingChanges and running the function. I've even added the .stop(); call to the end of my code and it still runs. Is there a way to stop everything that is observing changes?

Comment: I updated the value from the server side Mongo and it appears to not be watching anymore. I think I was actually seeing my client side reactive code calling my function.

Comment: I'm on the road right now, but check out the stop() function on the handle that is returned.