# How can meteor detect mongoDB changes?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am french so excuse my bad English.

I am actually learning meteor but I am asking something to myself.
How meteor can detect that a list of MongoDB results have changed ?
I think some events are fired when data are inserted/updated/removed.

That's cool but now imagine I have lot of people viewing blog posts, and they are filtered by categories. 
In SQL style, it would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE categories=?
```

(sorry I am not so familiar with MongoDB syntax at the moment)

Now I am inserting a new post with categories 5. The content of categories 5 is now refreshed in real time.
But what about others categories ? Is the query run again in background and it says

```
"select * from blog_posts WHERE categories=7" ... results are the same, nothing to change in the DOM.
```

So what if I have 9999 categories ? Is there query run again 9999 times for each different categories, just to update only one ?

I hope you understood my question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744661/how-could-meteor-know-mongodb-changes-instantly/20744805#20744805

Comment: This explained everything :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dzX_LEbZyI

Comment: Bienvenue a Meteor. C'est une platforme fantastique, presque magique.