# Meteor: How does liveQuery work on remote databases

Tags: javascript, meteor

Many people these days host their mongo databases on remote cloud services, how can meteor server watch the oplog for a remote database?

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver

Comment: @securecurve Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744661/how-could-meteor-know-mongodb-changes-instantly).

Comment: @DavidWeldon uestion was for remote databases, is it the same thing of local ones?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "local". If you set up your own local mongo DB, meteor will operate the same as if it were using a remote DB. E.g. It will fall back to poll-and-diff if you don't have an oplog URL. If by "local" you mean the DB that is created for you when doing development, then you don't need to worry about the connection details. Does that answer the question?