# Is meteor interested about what changed in DB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, real-time, database

I was thinking how `Meteor` detect changes in the database then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744661/how-could-meteor-know-mongodb-changes-instantly). Now I am wondering that does `Meteor` look which client is subscribing what, and what changed in the database? For example, if my client running a query for cats in the database, then a new dog added to database by another client. Will `Meteor` fire my query again? If yes, doesn't it affect the performance negatively?

Answer (score 0):

If CRUD operations are done collection A, all pages reading from collection A will be refreshed.

Yes, this behavior will affect speed, but Meteor is heavy because it has responsiveness in mind, not raw speed.